# Vue.js emit, pass array to child,map the array in child and emit event to parent, developer tool shows array is updated but the page not updated

Tags: vue.js

I am passing the array `drinks` as props to `Drinks.vue` and map elements inside of `Drinks.vue`
When I click the button, it is supposed to emit the event to change the element to 'Sold Out'.
However, when debugging using `console.log` or `Vue developer tool`, it shows the drinks array is updated, but the page itself doesn't re-render or update...
`Fruits` works well. Do you know why `Drinks.vue` could not update `drinks array`?

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Header :shop_name="shop_name" v-on:change_shop_name_event="change_shop_name($event)" />
    <Fruits :stocks="fruits" v-on:sell_fruit_event="update_fruit_status($event)" />
    <Drinks :stocks="drinks" v-on:sell_drink_event="update_drink_status($event)" />

    <Footer :shop_name="shop_name" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
import Fruits from "./components/Fruits.vue";
import Drinks from "./components/Drinks.vue";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Header,
    Fruits,
    Drinks,
    Footer,
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      shop_name: "Zowie Grocery",
      fruits: {
        Peach: 10,
        Apple: 10,
        Blueberry: 10,
        Strawberry: 10,
        Mongo: 10,
        Watermelon: 10,
      },
      drinks: ["beer", "orange juice", "milk shake", "tea", "coke"],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    change_shop_name: function (payload) {
      this.shop_name = payload;
    },

    update_fruit_status: function (payload) {
      this.fruits[payload] -= 1;
    },

    update_drink_status: function (index) {
      console.log(index);
      this.drinks[index] = "Sold Out";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Drinks.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>This is the drinks we have in stock</h2>
    <div v-for="(value,index) in stocks" :key="index">
      <p>{{value}}</p>
      <button @click="sell(index)">Sell</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "Drinks",
  props: ["stocks"],
  methods: {
    sell: function (index) {
      this.$emit("sell_drink_event", index);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead of `this.drinks[index] = "Sold Out"` :

```
this.drinks = this.drinks.map((k,idx)=> idx === index ? 'Sold Out' : k)
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that helped! check this might be interesting for you https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not reactive the way objects are in Vue.js. While just assigning a new value to an objects attribute just like that

`someObject.x = 'some value'`

it's not the same for an array and its elements. Just to clarify - yes, you can modify any index of an array but this won't trigger a re-render in Vue.js because of its reactivity system. If you modify an array by its index you've to take care about re-rendering the component yourself.

However, there's still hope. If you want Vue.js's reactivity system to take care about re-renders (even for Arrays) you've to use `Vue.$set` as stated in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

So for your example it should be like this.

```
this.$set(this.drinks, index, 'Sold Out');
```

This will not only update the array but also toggle your expected re-render.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation !! It is very clear! :)